# Android - Multiple Firebase environments for same app

Tags: android, firebase

I want to use different firebase environments for the same application depending on build type (debug/internal/release).  I am currently using different google-services.json for different build types to point at different firebase projects.  This part works fine.

Additionally, I am using app signing, so I sign with an upload key and google signs it for me with a key they keep safe.

The issue I am hitting is that (ideally) I also want to deploy my build types (staging and release) to the Play store under the same application.

However, I cannot set up two firebase projects such that they accept the same sha1 fingerprint.  I get an error saying the key is a duplicate when I try to add it to the second project.

I also use some other google api's and am hitting the same issue setting up the same fingerprint for android oauth credentials.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, have you been able to fix this?

Comment: I did not, sorry